# How do I configure Owin to use a custom AuthenticationHandler?

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect

I [have read](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1124) that it's possible to create a custom Owin authentication handler, but I can't figure out how to configure Owin to use my handler instead of the default one.

How do I tell Owin to use this class instead of the default?

```
public class XDOpenIdAuthHandler: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler
{
    public XDOpenIdAuthHandler(ILogger logger)
        : base(logger)
    {
    }

    protected override void RememberNonce(OpenIdConnectMessage message, string nonce)
    {
        //Clean up after itself, otherwise cookies keep building up until we've got over 100 and
        // the browser starts throwing errors. Bad OpenId provider.
        var oldNonces = Request.Cookies.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "nonce")).ToArray();
        if (oldNonces.Any())
        {
            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = Request.IsSecure
            };
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> oldNonce in oldNonces)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(oldNonce.Key, cookieOptions);
            }
        }
        base.RememberNonce(message, nonce);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add it as a part of a custom `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

```
public class CustomAuthMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public CustomAuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware nextMiddleware, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions authOptions)
        : base(nextMiddleware, authOptions)
    { }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new XDOpenIdAuthHandler(yourLogger);
    }
}
```

Then using it in the Startup.Auth for example:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<CustomAuthMiddleware>(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Be aware however that the Owin pipeline must not contain the default `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware`, otherwise it will still get called as part of the request pipe.